# Como contar as strings de uma variável

Tags: r

Tenho uma variável no banco de dados que está como `COMPOSIÇÃO DA COLIGAÇÃO` :

```
DS_COMPOSICAO DA COLIGACAO
AVANTE / PDT / PODE / PMN
AVANTE / PR / PV
DC / PRTB / AVANTE / SOLIDARIEDADE / PRP / PATRI 
DC / PSL / PRTB / SOLIDARIEDADE...
```

Eu queria criar mais uma variável contando o número de partidos dentro de cada coligação (cada linha).

Por ex: como na primeira linha há 4 partidos, na 3° 6 partidos.

Meu banco de dados tem 29.400 linhas então não dá para fazer manualmente.

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma é contar o caractere `"/"` e depois somar um, já que o primeiro partido nunca é precedido da barra.

```
library(tidyverse)
dado <- tibble(
  DS_COMPOSICAO_DA_COLIGACAO = c(
    "AVANTE / PDT / PODE / PMN", "AVANTE / PR / PV",
    "DC / PRTB / AVANTE / SOLIDARIEDADE / PRP / PATRI",
    "DC / PSL / PRTB / SOLIDARIEDADE"
  )
)


dado %>% 
  mutate(quantidade = str_count(DS_COMPOSICAO_DA_COLIGACAO, "/") + 1)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  DS_COMPOSICAO_DA_COLIGACAO                       quantidade
  <chr>                                                 <dbl>
1 AVANTE / PDT / PODE / PMN                                 4
2 AVANTE / PR / PV                                          3
3 DC / PRTB / AVANTE / SOLIDARIEDADE / PRP / PATRI          6
4 DC / PSL / PRTB / SOLIDARIEDADE                           4
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução sem dependência de pacotes externos:

```
partidos_txt <- c("AVANTE / PDT / PODE / PMN
AVANTE / PR / PV
DC / PRTB / AVANTE / SOLIDARIEDADE / PRP / PATRI 
DC / PSL / PRTB / SOLIDARIEDADE")

coligs <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(partidos_txt, split = "\\n")))

lista <- lapply(coligs, function(x){
  count <-  length(strsplit(x, "\\/")[[1]])

  return(data.frame(colig = x, count = count, stringsAsFactors = F))

  }) 

do.call(rbind, lista)
```

Produzindo:

```
> do.call(rbind, lista)
                                             colig count
1                        AVANTE / PDT / PODE / PMN     4
2                                 AVANTE / PR / PV     3
3 DC / PRTB / AVANTE / SOLIDARIEDADE / PRP / PATRI     6
4                  DC / PSL / PRTB / SOLIDARIEDADE     4
```

Answer (score 4):

Vou usar os dados tal como estão na [resposta do Tomás Barcellos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356278/como-contar-as-strings-de-uma-vari%c3%a1vel/356296#356296).

Uma só linha de código R base resolve o problema.

```
lengths(strsplit(dado[["DS_COMPOSICAO_DA_COLIGACAO"]], "/"))
#[1] 4 3 6 4
```

Agora é só criar a nova coluna com esta instrução.

```
dado$contagem <- lengths(strsplit(dado[["DS_COMPOSICAO_DA_COLIGACAO"]], "/"))
```

Answer (score -6):

Vamos pensar que "/" segue sempre este padrão informado.

```
declare @myvar varchar(20)
set @myvar = 'AVANTE / PDT / PODE / PMN'

select (len(@myvar) - len(replace(@myvar,'/',''))) + 1
```

Outra maneira é fazendo um split no "/"...

Comment: A pergunta é sobre [tag:r], a resposta não

Comment: Galera, valeu. Funcionou muito. Muito obrigado